# how to call two or more table from codeigniter and send or loaded to view

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I got the problem when I call to table I got error, how to call to table and loaded or send to view?

This is the code :

```
if($page == 'index') {
  $this->loggedIn();   
} else if($page == 'register') {
  $this->loggedRegisterIn();   
}
else {
  $this->notLoggedIn();

  $this->load->library('session');

  $this->load->model('model_users');

  $data['userData'] = $this->model_users->fetchUserData($this->session->userdata('user_id'));            
  $data2['userData2'] = $this->model_users->fetchUserData($this->session->userdata('user_id'));            
}

$this->load->view($page, $data, $data2);
```

this is error message :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: userData2
>
> Filename: views/dashboard.php
>
> Line Number: 179
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cobaan\e-magang\application\views\dashboard.php
>   Line: 179 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cobaan\e-magang\application\controllers\Pages.php
>   Line: 32 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cobaan\e-magang\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Answer (score 0):

this should be (**WRONG**)

```
  $data['userData'] = $this->model_users->fetchUserData($this->session->userdata('user_id'));            
  $data2['userData2'] = $this->model_users->fetchUserData($this->session->userdata('user_id'));            
}

$this->load->view($page, $data, $data2);
```

like this (**CORRECT**)

```
  $data['userData'] = $this->model_users->fetchUserData($this->session->userdata('user_id'));            
  $data['userData2'] = $this->model_users->fetchUserData($this->session->userdata('user_id'));            
}

$this->load->view($page, $data); # pass only one array with different array pointer
```

---

so **in view**

if `foreach`

```
foreach($userData as $item)
{

}

foreach($userData2 as $item)
{

}
```

if `print_r`

```
print_r($userData);
print_r($userData2);
```